# Qt, QTextEdit, how to turn all the content in QTextEdit into a image.

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I want to creat a image that contain the QTextEdit. 
And I write the following code to create the image.

```
QSize s = textEdit->frameSize();
QPixmap p(s);
textEdit->render(&p);
p.save("textContent.png", "PNG");
```

But it can not contain the invisible contents.(while the contents is too long in QTextEdit)

I wander if there is a way to create a image which contain all the content in QTextEidt. And how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think, you can do it like via `QTextDocument * QTextEdit::document ()` to receive `QTextDocument *` of your QTextEdit, and then draw it to QImage via `void QTextDocument::drawContents ( QPainter * p, const QRectF & rect = QRectF() )`

It draws the content of the document with painter p, clipped to rect. If rect is a null rectangle (default) then the document is painted unclipped.

check man here - http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qtextdocument.html#drawContents

Or - the other way - take all the text from TextEdit via `toPlainHtml() or toPlainText()` - what's more suitable for your needs and draw it to QImage via QPainter's method `QPainter::DrawText()`